# What does (this); mean on end of class method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does `(this);` mean on end of function in JavaScript?

I have a class with functions in it. Can I call `this.outputSome` within that class more times and/or when can I call it?

```
__construct = function(constructor){
    //some code
}(this);


this.outputSome = function(obj){
    //some
}(this);
```

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct? (in your case, `outputSome` is not a function but the return of function)

Comment: @chumkiu: As is `__construct`.

Comment: I asked what does it mean, not how to do it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that it executes itself with `this` as the parameter.

When you put parenthesis at the end of a function expression, it's self executing, and executes after it has been defined. The fact that `this` is inside the parenthesis suggests that it is passing `this` as the parameter.

Comment: *"When you put parenthesis at the end of a function declaratation..."* Function *expression*, not function declaration. Parens after a function *declaration* don't invoke it. (JavaScript [has both](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13), and they're slightly different. These are expressions, as they appear as right-hand values.)

Comment: So it's executing only one time after it has been defined?

Comment: Yes. It's executing and giving the return value to the variable.

Comment: @Maccath only in your case as you given. But there are more other cases apparently the same but are not the same! Just for clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically you define a variable:

```
var x = function(param) { /* do stuff */ };
```

The variable is a function so you can call that function with a parameter and save the return value in another variable:

```
var y = x(my_current_param);
```

Compressed into one line:

```
var y = function(param) { /* do stuff */ }(my_current_param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search self-invoking function. It call the function it-self as soon as it loads the JS.